# Let $f(x)=x^3+2x^2+1,\,\,g(x)=2x^2+x+2.$ Then over $\,\left(\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z\right)[x]\;$......

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am stuck on the following problem:

> Let $f(x)=x^3+2x^2+1,\,\,g(x)=2x^2+x+2.$ Then over $\,\left(\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z\right)[x]\;$, show that $f(x)$ is irreducible ,but $g(x)$ is not.

Can someone explain how to tackle it? Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

== Over *any* field, a polynomial of degree $\,\le 3\;$ is irreducible iff it has not root in that field

== $\,1^2-4\cdot2\cdot2=-15=0^2\pmod 3\;$, and thus in fact $\,g\,$ is a perfect square in $\,\left(\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z\right)[x]\;$

Comment: $-g$ is a perfect square.

Comment: Point taken: since $\; -2=1=1^2\pmod 3\;$ ,it must be $\,-g\;$ that is a square in that pol. ring since $\,2\,$ is not a square there. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: What happens if these polynomials have roots in $\mathbb Z_3$? What possible roots can they have? Can you check them?